# Animate oval in projectile motion

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to animate an oval/ball object to do a projectile motion, just like it was being kicked by a football player. I am not making any game.

What I lack is the technical knowledge of TCL, specially when one is using code written by someone else.

Shortly: an animated ball to do a projectile motion on a canvas controlled by start/stop button

There are [examples available](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4293), but I need better control and specially "Projectile Motion" in TCL.

I will really appreciate any code-related help, since I am not a good TCL-programmer (even after I am trying to learn its technicalities).

Comment: we're not here to write the code for you

Comment: I am not asking to write the code completely but any guidelines would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you're asking people who are passionate about tcl for help, saying you really don't like the language is a bad start. Most languages that's not Java or C keep existing because people love them. And people who don't like them don't use them enough to become experts who are most likely to give good answers on stackoverflow

Comment: I believe what you could have done is to take bits of the scripts from the wiki you found and try to understand it. `proc`s get executed only when the proc is called, so try to find the order the 'stuff' are being executed. Google functions that you are not familiar with (there are enough documentation I believe on the functions mentioned) and if you find a particular line you are not sure what happens, or can't understand after reading the docs, then ask here, mentioning the context. Also, if you don't like Tcl, you could perhaps code it in another language?

Comment: Thank you Jerry.
I am aware of basic maths and animation and changing coordinates etc. Unfortunately, I had been given an assignment (TCL code written by someone).. I've to implement this feature, and I am not really a TCL programmer, so struggling a little with syntax and technicalities.

Answer (score 1):

You draw ovals (including round ones) on a Tk `canvas` widget.

```
canvas .c -width 500 -height 500
pack .c
set ovalID [.c create oval 0 0 5 5]
```

You then animate it by changing its coordinates from time to time.

```
.c coords $ovalID $x $y [expr {$x + 5}] [expr {$y + 5}]
```

You have to permit the event loop to run between animation steps, though only idle event processing is vital (as Tk redraws on idle).

```
update idletasks
```

Then all you need to do is to compute the new position each timestep and use that coordinate update code above to move the oval; that's all animation is.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Appreciate it. You are really not like others here who appear to sound aloud rather than addressing the problem. Thanks once again really

Comment: @Anonymous We won't write the code for you, but we might provide pointers in the right direction. As a newcomer to the language, figuring out how to do animations of ovals is likely to take a little help _even when you've [done the tutorial](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)_.